# Transparent background with multiple controls

Tags: vb.net, label, controls, transparent

I'm trying to create an application where the user can move around three labels with transparent background. If one label will be located over the other, the second one should be visible.
For that purpose I created a custom control derivate because I want the custom label to have a transparent background -> and so I set SupportsTransparentBackColors and UserPaint via SetStyle()

```
Public Class Customlabel
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Control

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.SetStyle(Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
        Me.SetStyle(Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
        Me.SetStyle(Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
        InitializeComponents()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeComponents()
        Me.Width = 100
        Me.Height = 100
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Test", New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12), New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Black), New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0))
    End Sub
End Class
```

On the main form I created the labels as you could see:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim AB As Customlabel = New Customlabel
        AB.Left = 20
        AB.Top = 20
        AB.Name = "one"
        Me.Controls.Add(AB)

        Dim AC As Customlabel = New Customlabel
        AC.Left = 50
        AC.Top = 20
        AC.Name = "two"
        Me.Controls.Add(AC)

        Dim AD As Customlabel = New Customlabel
        AD.Left = 70
        AD.Top = 20
        AD.Name = "three"
        Me.Controls.Add(AD)
    End Sub

End Class
```

In spite of everything the labels are drawn like a rectangle without a transparent background and the overlapped CustomLabel is not visible. If i set the parent property of the labels to the Form, the background is transparent only relative to the Form. (not to the other CustomLabels)

Do somebody have an idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: You haven't changed anything, the Label control already has those style flags set.  What you are trying to do is not in general possible, transparency is simulated by getting the Parent of a control to paint the background.  Works fine, but of course you cannot see controls that are in between, you only see the parent.  Truly solving this problem requires avoiding controls that use a window.  Component vendors like Telerik specialize in that.  So does WPF.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look for WPF and Telerik.

Comment: It can be done if you are willing to manually draw the contents of your controls on the container. It is a lot of code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a good answer but could possibly work.
You could use images with a transparent background. like .png or .gif etc.
And then your image is your text.
You could do this in photoshop easily.
Just try to play around with it but I would draw the item myself. 
But an quick fix would be using a transparent image.

Answer (score -1):

too long;didnt read

To make any object transparent type in:

In case of the form:

```
Me.TransparencyKey = BackColor
```

To turn it back to normal:

```
Me.TransparencyKey = Transparent
```

Comment: If you haven't read the question, it's best not to try to make a wild guess at an answer.